# Upgrade MySQL Server 3.51 to 8.0 with WinMySQL from 2001

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

We have a live MySQL server at the company where everything comes together. It was created around 1998 and has been running continuously ever since.

The MySQL version is 3.51.
WinMySQL version 1.4 from 2001.

I was just born at the time....

I need a secure way to migrate the data to a newer version, as I can't access this database with any current software.

mysqld-max-nt.exe is the name of the service.

Only the 2001 version of WinMySQLAdmin still works.I did find a way to create a DB dump at some point, but it could not be read by any version of MySQL.

I need a way where I can upgrade to MySQL 8.0 without data loss.

Comment: What does the DB dump contain? SQL commands or is it some kind of a binary dump? I don't know when mysqldump utility was created, but if your mysql installation includes that utility, then you could use it to dump your database in sql format. However, be prepared that you need to manually tweak the sql file to get it run on mysql 8.

Comment: If you do have a datadump, the modern version of your WinMySQL is going to be MySQL Workbench, and you can import data with a few clicks.  Is this going to work perfectly with 20 year old data and no tweaks?  Probably not .. but if it was easy you wouldn't have work to do :)  Download here -> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: So I got the dump via the mysql binaries. Then I had to convert the file to ISO-8859-2. Now I copied the dump to MySQL Workbench and try to run the script and work my way from error message to error message. Only 438,000 rows left. I'll let you know if it works. Not an easy way, but manageable. Thanks

Comment: It is a giant task, but looks like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to export the data to excel or csv or txt format, not sql format, because mysql 3 is too old and many data types have changed, which is why the current version can't read this file format.
Then create a new table (new data type) in mysql, and then import the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dump complete database structure (tables, views, procedures, triggers and so on) without the data.
2. Export tables data to separate CSV files using SELECT INTO OUTFILE.
3. Edit dump file manually adjusting it to current syntax.
4. Divide dump file on two parts - tables only in the first dump file and all another objects in the second dump file.
5. Import first dump file on new server.
6. Import CSV files on new server.
7. Import second dump file.
8. Check that all data is imported correctly.